# How can i add angular expression inside an attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which uses an options attribute to config:

```
<div something something-options="{
    'count': 'item-0'
}">
```

This is inside an ng-repeat. How can i add the repeat $index into the options attribute? These won't work:

```
<div something something-options="{
    'count': 'item-'+$index
    'count': 'item-'+{{$index}}
}">
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/VMXdjR7TJCZGd5ly4Bdl

Answer (score 0):

> In your sample you try to get object as string, but in this sample we try to get it as variable in the $scope.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.b = [1,2,3];
});

app.directive("something", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      somethingOptions: "="
    },
    link: function($scope) {
      console.log($scope.somethingOptions);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="a in b" something something-options="{
    'count': 'item-'+$index
}">{{a}}</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Check 2 variants with and without 2 way binding plnkr.co/edit/N7szNXx1iULLDb6oBp9J?p=preview & plnkr.co/edit/m2yGZLoY67ahjIRmFCne?p=preview